# What is the difference between using gpio_tlmm_config and gpio_request + gpio_direction_input/output?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Please someone explain the difference in usage of 1.`gpio_tlmm_config` and 2.`gpio_request` + `gpio_direction_input`/`gpio_direction_output`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[gpio_tlmm_config](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/arm/msm/gpiomux.txt)        -"History"
[gpio_request](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/arm/msm/gpiomux.txt)            - "Static Configurations
[gpio_direction_input](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio.txt)    - "Using GPIOs"
[gpio_direction_output](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio.txt)   -"Using GPIOs"

`gpio_tlmm_config` is first-generation API for gpio configuration &
 multiplexing on msm while `gpio_request` a request which carries an implicit `msm_gpiomux_get`. `gpio_direction_input & gpio_direction_output` normally issue these calls from task context.

Comment: The last two links are broken